# PowerShell to find traveling number

Tags: powershell

How this possible to find on traveling digit (number) which is traveling inside the string.

Like i have string which always contains a lot of different characters and I need to find one single digit.

Example:

> cv45H.cdxe**5**Hdse.456yutfgH.GSAWfYdfx.zd776r345.eytuhjg.fdyh$76

In this example it should return **5**

> cbn.tg444.33Fvbsery.DDfbY&sdcbnBBB.#353fdd4437.809c**2**g345.fvbwse645

In this example should return **2**

Comment: Is there some logic as to what digit you want to find in any of these strings?

Comment: I would use Regex but what are the conditions for your digits? Based on what should they be returned? What did you do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grab the first single-digit number from a string:

```bsh
$strings = 'cv45H.cdxe5Hdse.456yutfgH.GSAWfYdfx.zd776r345.eytuhjg.fdyh$76','cbn.tg444.33Fvbsery.DDfbY&sdcbnBBB.#353fdd4437.809c2g345.fvbwse645'

foreach($string in $strings){    
    if($string -match '(?<!\d)(?<digit>\d)(?!\d)'){
        Write-Host "Found digit:" $Matches['digit']
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No single digit number found!"
    }
}
```

The regular expression pattern consists of:

```
(?<!        # negative look-behind
  \d        # asserting there's no digit behind
)           # end look-behind
(?<digit>   # named group 'digit'
  \d        # matching a single digit
)           # end named group
(?!         # negative look-ahead
  \d        # asserting there's no digit ahead
)           # end look-ahead
```

Comment: This is a totally great solution is too!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "details" you provide, I assume you are looking for the digit that has no neighboring digits. The regex for this is `\D(\d)\D` ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1ZxYk/3)):

```bsh
PS> 'cv45H.cdxe5Hdse.456yutfgH.GSAWfYdfx.zd776r345.eytuhjg.fdyh$76' -replace '^.*\D(\d)\D.*$', '$1'
5
PS> 'cbn.tg444.33Fvbsery.DDfbY&sdcbnBBB.#353fdd4437.809c2g345.fvbwse645' -replace '^.*\D(\d)\D.*$', '$1'
2
PS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Thanks folks.
Tomas, special to you. I didn't know about "https://regex101.com"

I found solution:
Its like that [[:alpha:]]\d[[:alpha:]]

Comment: from what i can tell, neither dotnet or the PoSh subset of that support POSIX character classes. have you tested that regex pattern in powershell? [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

here is yet another method. [*grin*] it aint as efficient as the primarily regex versions, but it may be easier to understand.

this presumes your "traveling number" is simply the 1st single-digit number in the string. what it does ...

- saves the string to a $Var
- splits on the non-digits
  this consumes the split targets and gives you a bunch of strings that consist solely of digits OR are blank.
- filters out the blank items
  splitting on any non-digit series gives a blank item from splitting the alfa strings.
- sorts by the length of the strings
- grabs the 1st item

the code ...

```
$Test = 'cv45H.cdxe5Hdse.456yutfgH.GSAWfYdfx.zd776r345.eytuhjg.fdyh$76'
(($Test -split '\D').
    Where({
        $_
        }) |
    Sort-Object Length)[0]
```

output = `5`